# Observe firebase database on changes typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

So I'm calling to my firebase realtime database in an angular service like so:

```
readItems() {
    return this.af.database.ref(`/path`)
      .on('value', snap => this.callback(snap.val()));
  }
```

callback just modifies the response to my needs. What I need to do is grab this modified data in the component I'm calling `readItems` from. Here's that call in said component:

```
this.service.readItems();
```

I want to to find when this finishes and returns the modified response using an observable or promise with a `subscribe` or `then`. I cannot figure how to do this and any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Subject from rxjs in the callback you pass into the `on` function and subscribe to it:

```
valueChanged$ = new Subject();

callback(val) {
    // some code ...
    valueChanged$.next(val); // pass whatever you need to receive in the subscription
}

readItems() {
  return this.af.database.ref(`/path`)
    .on('value', snap => this.callback(snap.val()));
}
```

Then later in your code:

```
this.valueChanged$.subscribe(data => doStuff(data));
this.service.readItems();
```

Comment: This doesn't work though because firebase.database().ref().on does't return an observable. See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! If you don't mind, what is reason for adding the $ at the end of the subject variable, just common practice?

Comment: Awesome! The $ sign is just a convention when working with streams and observables. It makes it clear to whomever is reading the code that it is a stream.

Comment: I'm glad it works! Would you consider upvoting as well?

Comment: Thanks @BorisLobanov your answer helped me as well, upvoted :)